# symbolic link in /media

Tags: command-line

I've tried to create a symbolic link from a file in `/media/myuser/nameofdevice/myfolderA` to the folder `/media/myuser/nameofdevice/myfolderB` with the command ln but I get an error. Is possible to do it or it is impossible to do? And if I can't, why?

The error is:

```
ln: failed to create the symbolic link '/media/myuser/nameofdevice/myfolderB/animacion_cgi_theo_jansen.mp4': Operation not permitted
```

I tried with sudo and without it. I'm in the right folder where file is.

```
sudo ln -s animacion_cgi_theo_jansen.mp4 /media/myuser/nameofdevice/myfolderB
```

Comment: `but I get an error` - the error message is the most important information if you want an answer...

Comment: Should be no problem. Without seeing the command you typed or your error message all I can suggest is using the correct format `ln -s source-file symlink`. So for example you would use `ln -s /media/myuser/nameofdevice/myfolderA/FILENAME.FILETYPE /media/myuser/nameofdevice/myfolderB/`

Comment: @Cornelius I have added the error log

Comment: put `sudo` in front of `ls` and try again.

Comment: @TomBrossman this is what I do and I get the error that I have added. I think it is caused for be a media device the destiny but I dont know

Comment: @Cornelius I have tried with sudo and without.

Comment: and the filesystem is NTFS perhaps?

Comment: Also, try using <tab> to autocomplete and make sure you are getting the path correct. For example, `sudo ln -s animacion<tab> /media/myuser/nameofdevice/myfolder<tab>`. If you use this, you will be able to confirm the paths are exactly correct as Ubuntu will not autocomplete incorrect paths.

Comment: @Rinzwind I have written df -hT and says that it is vfat

Comment: @TomBrossman Thx, I checked it twice before post the question and it not the error

Comment: @YábirGarcia and symlinks are supported by vfat since when? ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind thx so I will reformat the USB memory. NTFS is the right yeah?

Comment: No? for symlinks you need a POSIX filesystem. So ext3 or ext4, not a Windows filesystem.

Comment: @Rinzwind ok thx :)

Answer (score 1):

@Rinzwind Has answered me. The usb mounted was in vfat and It doens't accept symbolic links. So the solution was reformat it to ext4 and now I can create the symbolic links

Comment: Just be aware that other devices will likely not be able to read the new file format.